# How to allow access to Docker container in MERN project only through specific URL while blocking ports?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a MERN project set up with Docker. Development environment is fine; it's production I'm having trouble with.

This is the behavior that I desire:

- In Development:

  - This is the state of the containers:

    - Nodemon runs in the node express image (from node:alpine) container with *port 9000* open to the host. (this is the backend/api)
    - MongoDB runs in its own container based on the official image with *port 27017* open to the host. (this is the database)
    - React runs with warm reload in its image (from node:alpine) container with *port 3000* open to the host. (this is the frontend)
- In Production:

  - This is the state of the containers:

    - Node runs in the node express image (from node:alpine) container with *no ports* open to the host.
    - MongoDB runs in its own container based on the official image with *no ports* open to the host.
    - React runs in its image (from nginx:alpine) container with *port 80* open to the host.

The backend/api refers to the database using the container name, and the frontend/react container refers to the backend using the container name.

I put `proxy: localhost:9000` in the react **package.json** file. In production, I put the following in the **nginx.conf** file.

```
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
}
```

In the production docker-compose.yml file, I removed `expose: "9000"` and `ports: "9000:9000"` that were present in the docker-compose.yml file. I run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.production.yml up`.

---

My problem is that the ports "localhost:9000" and "localhost:27017" are still exposed in production for some reason. I want all routes, except for "example.com/api", to go through React. Only "example.com/api" must go directly to the backend.

Also, I'm not sure if this is related, but is there a way to make sure "example.com/api" goes to the backend without having to do `require("express")().get('/api'...`? As in, just doing `require("express")().get('/'...` takes calls to "example.com/api" by default.

Note: I used networks, not links, in order to connect containers together. Backend is connected to both React and MongoDB, while React and MongoDB are not connected to each other.

---

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
##############################
# Back-End Container
##############################
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: ./backend/
      target: development
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "9000"
    environment:
      - MONGO_URI=mongodb://db:27017/db
      - PORT=9000
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - DEBUG=app
      - JWT_SECRET=secretsecret
      - JWT_EXPIRY=30d
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9229:9229"
    volumes:
      - "./backend/:/home/node/app/"
      - /home/node/app/node_modules/
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - client
      - server
##############################
# Front-End Container
##############################
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend/
      target: development
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "3000"
      - "35729"
    environment: 
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - REACT_APP_PORT=3000
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "35729:35729"
    volumes:
      - "./frontend/:/home/node/app/"
      - /home/node/app/node_modules/
    networks:
      - client
##############################
# MongoDB Container
##############################
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/data/db/
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - server
networks:
  client:
  server:
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

Here is my .env file

```
MONGO_URI=db:27017/somedb?authSource=admin
PORT=9000
MONGO_PORT=27017
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongoadmin
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=somedb
NODE_ENV=production
```

Here is my docker.compose.production.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
##############################
# Back-End Container
##############################
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    init: true
    environment:
      - MONGO_URI=mongodb://${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}:${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}@${MONGO_URI}
      - PORT=${PORT}
      - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
    build:
      context: ./backend/
      target: production
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - client
      - server
##############################
# Front-End Container
##############################
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend/
      target: production
    restart: always
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
    expose:
      - "80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - client
##############################
# MongoDB Container
##############################
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/data/db/
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks: 
      - server
networks:
  client:
  server:
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

Dockerfiles only have FROM, WORKDIR, RUN, COPY, and CMD.

Comment: Did you try swapping the positions of the two location blocks.

Comment: Can you include your `docker-compose.yml` file (either version) in the question?  I’m a little suspicious that the `localhost:9000` address works at all.

Comment: Added docker-compose.yml, .env, and docker-compose.production.yml files @DavidMaze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I run docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.production.yml up.

Why did I include the development docker-compose.yml? All I had to do was remove that part and run docker-compose.production.yml directly. Didn't need any overriding done.

Solution was to run:

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml up`

For those looking for why proxy didn't lead to root of backend was because [I didn't include a forward slash in the url of the proxy in the nginx.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54723811/1934402).