# Nginx proxy pointing to root of node server URL but node responds to full URL?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have an Nginx server running and redirecting proxy to a node server:

```
  server {
        listen      80 default_server;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://node_server:9000;
    }
```

Site URL is `example.com`, but when you go to `example.com/api`, it should go to the root of the node server.

When I do `app.use('/', indexRouter);`, though, it doesn't work.

I have to do `app.use('/api', indexRouter);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
    listen      80 default_server;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://node_server:9000/;
        #                                 ^
    }
}
```

Had to add a forward slash.